# REST API for turn based game?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

We're working on a turn based multiplayer game, for which we need to implement some backend functionality which will keep track of players data and games.

My first approach has been to design a REST API using NodeJS and MongoDB that will let the client access this data. I'm not very much into web services but as far as I've learnt, REST involves exchanges of information on the whole data model. So lets say I have a Game model, which contains information such as the score, the board state and the players involved, then I cannot just send a request to retrieve a certain game's score, but I need to send a GET request for the whole Game model, and then read the score from it, something like:

```
GET http://restserver.com/games/12d3k351s
```

Is this correct or am I making a wrong assumption?

If this were the case, there would be multiple times when I would like to retrieve a complete list of games, but not their whole board state which would be a bigger chunk of data. Would it be wise to separate the board state into a different model then, for example, as a means to reduce the volume of unnecessary data being transferred on every game information request?

If I had to design the database without the REST API I would certainly keep the board state as property of the Game class inside the Games collection, so it sounds like not the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a good experience with [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/). It's REST-ish, and covers many needs that may arise when building an api server these days. Your exact scenario, with partial get, is called [Sparse Fieldsets](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) there.

> A client **MAY** request that an endpoint return only specific [fields](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-fields) in the response on a per-type basis by including a `fields[TYPE]` parameter.
>
> ```
> GET /articles?include=author&fields[articles]=title,body&fields[people]=name HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/vnd.api+json
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much Sergio! This totally answers my question.

Partial get is exactly the term I was looking for but I wasn't aware that it was an allowed practice in REST.

Also, json-api seems like a very useful resource, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether or not you store the board data together with game data or not. You can just query the game data without the board data. MongoDB allows you to do that.

Here is an example:

```
db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1 } )
```

This means "only return the item, status and _id fields of inventory items that have status of 'A'".

You can just do

```
db.games.find({}, { gameData: 1, gameStatus: 1 });
```

and get just gameData and gameStatus of all games.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that, but thanks for your help anyway! My question was mainly if returning only a subset of the model data was allowed in a REST environment or not.

Comment: The question was about api design, though.

Comment: It is allowed. In fact, it's a widely practised thing. It is really common in restful apis to have two different endpoints for retrieving summary information on an entire table and retrieving detail information on a single column.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct or am I making a wrong assumption?

Wrong assumption.  REST API are not about exposing your data models, but are about how you expose the integration protocol.

There's absolutely no reason that you can't have a document that shows you what the current score of a game is.

> If this were the case, there would be multiple times when I would like to retrieve a complete list of games, but not their whole board state which would be a bigger chunk of data. Would it be wise to separate the board state into a different model then, for example, as a means to reduce the volume of unnecessary data being transferred on every game information request?

Start from this question -- how would you do it as [a web site](http://www.espn.com/mlb/scoreboard/_/date/20170627)?  Lots of different fit-for-purpose documents, and navigation links with semantic cues to help consumers find the document they need.

Do that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, indeed I noticed that I had made the wrong assumption.